# What features are supported by Android's Google accounts authenticator?

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-account

The [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#hasFeatures%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) for the `hasFeatures` method of Android's `AccountManager` has the following to say about which features are supported by each authenticator:

> Account features are authenticator-specific string tokens identifying
>   boolean account properties. For example, features are used to tell
>   whether Google accounts have a particular service (such as Google
>   Calendar or Google Talk) enabled. The feature names and their meanings
>   are published somewhere associated with the authenticator in question.

Does anybody have any idea where *"somewhere associated with the authenticator in question"* actually is for the authenticator used for Google accounts?  I would like to know which features are supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I still haven't found any official documentation but I have figured out the main use case, that of determining whether a Google account is associated with a specific Google service.

There is a feature for each service and the feature name is of the form `service_<service_code_name>`.  Using [this (possibly out-of-date) list of service code names](http://web.archive.org/web/20120107132009/http://ruscoe.net/google/google-account-service-names/) for Google services, we can check for features such as `service_lh2` (Picasa), `service_groups2` (Google Groups) and `service_mail` (GMail).

Comment: The link of "possibly out-of-date" codenames, is now entirely out of date. The link is dead.

Comment: What are those "features" ? where can I find them? Is it possible to filter the accounts by those that you can set for contacts, for when you create a new contact (or modify one)?